# Cocoapods error when trying to pod install Firebase- nanaimo

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-storage

I'm having some trouble with Cocoapods. Whenever I try to pod install on Terminal it starts loading and then gives me a huge error message. I'm trying to pod install Firebase/Storage to enable my XCode iOS app to communicate with Firebase's servers. Here is the error message terminal gives me when I try pod install. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
### Error
```

`` LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:23:in `read_from_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:855:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:854:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:854:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:849:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:66:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:149:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:110:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:60:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ``

```
――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
```

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall via the terminal

```
sudo gem uninstall
```

then reinstall

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then follow the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Also try

```
sudo gem install nanaimo
```

Comment: Did that and it still gives me the same error... Do you have any other advice. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @CoolPenguin Rats. Ok. Try this shot in the dark *sudo gem install nanaimo*

Comment: I figured that out 5 mins ago. It works now! Thanks so much.

Comment: @CoolPenguin Excellent! Glad you got it working. That was super frustrating.